# Firebase - orderByChild integer not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database and I want to sort all `posts` by their `score` (an integer), I thought it would be super easy because I'm currently doing `orderByChild('created')` and it works perfectly, but for some reason `orderByChild('score')` doesn't work.

Here is my database structure:

[image]

`score` is an integer that can be negative, positive or 0.

The JavaScript I'm using:

```
  this.subscription = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.userData.location)
  .orderByChild('score')
  .startAt(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000)) //last 24 hrs
  .limitToFirst(10);
  this.subscription.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
        console.log(this.postFeed)
  });
```

The weird thing is, the `console.log` isn't even firing so it's not even getting to that stage for some reason, but if I change `.orderByChild('score')` to `.orderByChild('created')` it works exactly as expected...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using AngularJS 1.X, or Angular 2+? At the moment your question has both tags annotated. And how far is Angular even relevant to the question? You might even remove both tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it might be something to do with this line

```
.startAt(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000))
```

This will create a `startAt` query which would currently be `1519944842592`

This means that it's trying to start at that specific number. So it's not looking for `-1`, it's starting the query at `1519944842592`.

You would need to incorporate a `createdAt` object within your schema and query that first.

The reason your `.orderByChild('created')` works is because it's a date object which is before the `startAt` query so that's why it works correctly :)

Comment: Yes I just confirmed that removing the `.startAt` fixes the issue, so how would you recommend I fix this problem if I need the past 24 hours?

Comment: Firebase is limited to only one query at a time. If you only need one day, then you need to do `.orderByChild('created')` then order it by score yourself. Since each method after takes into account he previous one you were starting at that score.